# How to say age restrictions in movies?

Tags: usage

How would I denote the spectrum of film age restrictions as spoken in France? And how could I go about doing this in a colloquial manner when discussing movies casually with a friend? Things like:

> It's been a while since I've seen a G-rated movie.

or

> I can't believe it's rated R!

I've seen a range of things from *interdit aux mineurs* to *classé-R*. But from what I understand, the content rating system varies from `U to -18`. So how would I go about expressing each respective rating in a casual tone?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In France, there is no casual shortcut I'm aware of. We say the age under which the movie is restricted:

> ***Interdit aux moins de*** 18 (or *16* or *12*) *ans*.

A -18 movie is also called ***interdit aux mineurs*** and might be ***classé X***.

On TV, there is an extra level:

> ***Interdit/déconseillé aux moins de*** 10 ans.

U rated movies are called ***tous publics***.

Comment: A shortcut could be omitting "ans".

Comment: Quelques détails ici : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commission_de_classification_des_%C5%93uvres_cin%C3%A9matographiques. Mais cela correspond à la réponse donnée

Comment: Now that I think about it, I'm pretty sure I've even heard the shortcut *Ce film est "moins de 16"*.

Comment: @Destal Yes, *ans* might be omitted although in my opinion it is rare.